# Cannot see form fields when creating a Webform in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to create a questionnaire using Webform 3.18 in Drupal 7. However, when I create the form, I cannot see any form fields to add to it. I cannot figure out what to do. Anybody has any suggestions? I am also attaching a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. A module called 'Form builder Webform UI" was enabled which was causing the problem. Disabling it fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

I my case are version of Form builder and Webform. if is used Form Builder 7.x-1.6 and Webform 7.x-4.2 the symptoms are as is indicated here. If is used Webform 7.x-4.1 or 7.x-3.21 and Form Builder 7.x-1.5 (does not work with 7.x-1.6) the things works ok. Seems could be related with https://www.drupal.org/node/2383285